# ContainsKey doesn't recognise existing key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following piece of Java code where I'm working with a set of words from a StringTokenizer to be added to a HashMap. Each word from the StringTokenizer should be added to the Map as a key and the value of the key should be incremented by one in case a word is already present.

```
Map<String, Integer> hM = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fileContent, this.delimiters, false);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = st.nextToken();
    String key = token.trim().toLowerCase();
    if(!stopWordsList.contains(key))
    {
        if(hM.containsKey(key))
        {
            Integer newValue = hM.get(key)+1;
            //hM.put(key, hM.get(key) + 1);

            hM.put(key, newValue );
            //System.out.println(key + " " + newValue);
        }
        else
        {
            hM.put(key, 1);
            System.out.println(key + " " + "1");
        }
    }
}
```

The trouble is that some words are added to the HashMap multiple times with the value of 1, so it looks like the containsKey method does not find some of the existing keys. However a lot of the cases the words are found and the value increments properly.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it will be useful if you include an example of "some words are added to the HashMap multiple times with the value of 1", i.e., a set of words for which the error happens so they can be used to check the problem.

Comment: I added the Map declaration to my question. To @Nananda's question, for example the word 'list' keeps being added to the map again and again with initial value of 1, other words i.e. massachusetts has value of 18.

Comment: have you checked for trailing space in the words that keep getting added ?

Comment: When you say that "some words are added to the HashMap multiple times" do you mean that there are multiple keys with seemingly the same value? That would certainly be strange. It would be worth iterating through the map values and printing their `toString` and `hashCode` - if they are not the same then there's definitely something wrong with the keys you are adding.

Comment: Is your map accessible outside this particular method? Is anything else modifying it?

Comment: @RealSkeptic nothing else is accessing this Map.

Comment: @Manos, I do toLowercase and trim before I add the key to the Map.

Comment: Is the map declared as a field or a local variable?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, it's a local variable

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible explanations:

- You have a race condition.  Specifically, this code is being executed intensively by multiple threads without proper synchronization.  If access / updates are not properly synchronized, one thread may not be seeing the results of a second thread's updates; i.e `hM.containsKey(key)` can return `false` when it should return `true`.
- Some other part of your code is removing entries, or clearing or reinitializing the `HashMap`.
- The scoping of `hM` is wrong, and this code is seeing a different `HashMap` instance each time.
- The code you have shown us is not an accurate representation of the code that is actually being run; e.g.

  - you have changed something in writing the question, or
  - you have a problem with your build / deploy / run procedures.

Comment: I'm suspecting race condition as well between multiple threads. How can I work around it quickly?

Comment: You should not "work around it quickly".  A quick workaround is likely to lead to other problems (like a concurrency bottleneck ... or a fix that isn't a fix).

Comment: One approach would be to use a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>` ... using `putIfAbsent(key, new AtomicInteger(...))` to deal with the race condition in the case where you are creating a new entry.  But think about it VERY carefully.  Don't just rush in with a "quick fix".